# combineWith vs onValues in Bacon.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, reactive-programming, bacon.js

I have 2 Bacon.jQuery `Models` (but the problem can be illustrated with any Bacon `Observable`).

I have 3 combo boxes: `foo`, `bar` and `quux`. `bar` depends on `foo` and `quux` depends on a combination of `bar` and `quux`. There is a `findQuux` function which finds a value for `quux` combobox from `foo` and `bar`.

If a user changes `foo` combobox, the values in `bar` and `quux` boxes are selected. Here is a working implementation of `quux` selection:

```
// WORKS
var quuxBus = new Bacon.Bus()
Bacon.onValues(fooModel, barModel, function (foo, bar)
{
    quuxBus.push(findQuux(foo, bar))
})
quuxModel.addSource(quuxBus.toProperty('quux4'))
```

There is a little problem with this solution as I need `'quux4'` hack to set `quux` correctly on page load. But the following simpler solution doesn't work at all:

```
// DOESN'T WORK
var quuxCombo = Bacon.combineWith(findQuux, fooModel, barModel)
quuxModel.addSource(quuxCombo)
```

The problem is that `findQuux` expects a valid combination of `foo` and `bar` and crashes when fed with an impossible combination for which a `quux` cannot be found.

The `onValues/push` solution works because `findQuux` is called only once when a user changes `foo` combobox. The `bacon.combineWith` solution doesn't work because `findQuux` is called twice.

What is the recommended way to implement the data source for `quuxModel`? Coding `findQuux` defensively is not an option.

The full code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/5zp4D/8/

**Update:** There are already sensible values for `foo` and `bar` from page load. As can be seen from the fiddle link `fooModel` is initialized with an explicit value, and `barModel` is recalculated from that initial value:

```
var fooModel = Bacon.$.selectValue(fooDom, 'foo2-value')
var barModel = Bacon.$.selectValue(barDom)

barModel.addSource(fooModel.map(function (x)
{
    return json[x][1].val
}))
```

`foo` and `bar` never take invalid values. Moreover, `bar` is repopulated once a user changes `foo`, so only valid combinations are seen in the UI.

The problem with `combineWith` approach is that when a user switches `foo` then `findQuux` function is called twice with intermediate values, and one of the intermediate combinations is incorrect, while the combination constituents are separately correct. I changed the fiddle to better illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5zp4D/12/

As can be seen from `var json` the valid combinations are 1-1, 1-2, 2-3, 2-4 and 2-5.

I uncommented the broken version, added logging. When you select `foo1` and then select back `foo2` in the first combobox, you get 4 messages in the log instead of 3:

On page load you see that `quux` value is correctly initialized (2-4):

```
"valid combination of foo2-value and bar4-value"
```

When you select `foo1` instead of `foo2` you see that `findQuuxDef` is called with 1-4 (`foo` is new, `bar` is old) and then with 2-4 (`foo` is new, `bar` is new):

```
"invalid combination of foo1-value and bar4-value"
"valid combination of foo1-value and bar2-value"
```

My problem is that invalid intermediate combinations don't happen with `onValues/push` approach, and I'd like to know what is an idiomatic recommended approach to UI with linked elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with having `quuxCombo` only output valid values for `findQuux`. I'd prefer having sensible values for inputs `foo` and `bar` from page load, but if that's not possible (why not?), I'd use `filter` on the inputs. For instance,

```
var quuxCombo = Bacon.combineWith(findQuux, fooModel.filter(validFoo), barModel.filter(validBar))
```

I guess though, that you want to start with some initial value before valid input exists. For this, I added a new method `Property.startWith` into Bacon.js 0.6.15. So, now you can

```
var quuxCombo = Bacon.combineWith(findQuux, fooModel.filter(validFoo), barModel.filter(validBar)).startWith("quux4")
```

Comment: Updated my question. `fooModel.filter(validFoo)` won't work because `foo` and `bar` are always valid separately. It's their combination that is invalid, as pairwise search doesn't find the combination in `var json`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So `bar` is calculated based on `foo`. The onValues approach works because of the way Property update atomicity is updated. The output from the "combination tree" of the Properties will be atomic but inside the "tree", there's no atomicity. So, your combinator functions may be called for invalid combos as well.

Comment: So I don't have an answer ready for you at the time. I'm thinking about adding some kind of way to indicate that a certain combinator needs to be called for valid (atomically updated) combos only...

Comment: Please make an Issue on Github